# Span and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am reading this text:

[image]

Is my understanding of this correct? Because any two vectors added together are still a linear combination of vectors in S, then it is closed under addition. Any two vectors added together are still in span(s), so it is closed under addition, and therefore span(s) is still a subspace because one principle of being a subspace is that it is closed under addition.

Comment: "*...so it is closed under addition, and therefore span(s) is still a subspace because...*"  All that you personally typed has had to do with the property that a subspace must be closed under addition.  It is not *solely* from this property that we prove that span(S) is a subspace.  We must also show that it is closed under scalar multiplication (*which is included in the pictured proof, but not in any of the text you personally wrote*).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct. You could add to that that iv $v\in\operatorname{span}S$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then $\alpha v\in\operatorname{span}S$ too. So, $\operatorname{span}S$ is closed both under addition and multiplication by scalars.